# Risk of attack through query string

Tags: .net, security, qwik

I am developing a website that uses **qwik.js** client technology and **.net 7** back-end technology. I give all the query parameters that the user enters in url to the api to search for data.
I in api extract the items required for the search from the sent query parameters And I search according to the extracted items.

Is it possible to attack even though I only extract the necessary materials from query parameters?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cross side scripting should be no issue due to URL in between.

`useLocation` returns URL.

Please make sure you don't just pass stuff to dangerousSetInnerHTML.

But this does not mean, that you can be 100 percent safe for other things like SQL injections.